# Error in deserializing body of request message for operation

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm writing a service Adapter to use web services hosted by an another vendor (Pega). Changing this service is not an option for me.
When I'm calling a method I get the error :

> **"Error in deserializing body of request message for operation"**

I tried increasing maxStringContentLength and all. Nothing worked.
When examining the response XML I see empty values for few long and int variables I believe this is the reason.

Is there is any fix for this?

Comment: It is deserializing.Excuse the auto correct.

Comment: This link may be helpful to you http://marcipsen.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/wcf-error-in-deserializing-body-of-request-message-for-operation

Comment: Thanks Karthik, but I already tried changing settings at app.config. As I have mentioned I believe the cause might be having empty values for few long and int variables in the response XML. Need a fix for that from client end.

Comment: Is there an inner exception with more details?

Comment: Only thing makes sense is : at System.Number.ParseInt64(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
                 at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToInt64(String s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got resolved after removing empty tags from the service end.
No solution found from .Net client end.

Comment: I had service end configured to send a 0 instead of null element.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed my problem with 2 things: 1) change the return type of the operation from the simple string type to a custom class type decorated with DataContractAttribute. 2) I uninstalled the HttpWatch 7.0.22 which interferes with the jQuery call. It is the HttpWatch that blocked the operation argument from being sent.

Comment: @PAVITRA - I have the same problem and couldn't figure out how to solve by following your instructions: how did you actually do it? What empty tags? From which file?

Comment: In the response I had empty values for few long and int not null able fields.This is normally not supposed to happen.
When trying to deserialize this response the error was thrown.
Couldn't find any fix from .NET end for this.
So my last option was to change the third party service.
I had it changed to send 0 instead of empty tags for long,int fields.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing format of one of request parameters. Date was passed as a text and service was unable to parse provided date format.

Not sure why service expected date as a string though, but this was out of scope that time.