# Php soap data send error

Tags: php, soap, webservice-client

When sending data to the SomeMethod() method, the 1 excess parameter returns as an error.

My Code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('site_url/?wsdl');
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$loginparam = array('userName'=>'name','password'=>'pass','trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 0);   


$session = $client->OturumAc($loginparam);
$SoapIcHeader = new SoapHeader("http://sanayi.gov.tr","TokenId",$session->OturumAcResult);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($SoapIcHeader);
$OturumUzat = $client->OturumDogrulaVeUzat($session ->OturumAcResult);

$param["BosAgirligi"] = "20";
$param["CalismaBasinci"] = "5";
$param["DoluAgirligi"] = "1";
$param["SonMuayeneTarihi"] = "2017-08-01 10:19:04";
$param["SonMuayeneYapanFirmaMersisNo"] = "123456789";
$param["SuKapasitesi"] = "1";
$param["TestBasinci"] = "10";
$param["DolumBasinci"] = "15";
$param["EtKalinligi"] = "3";
$param["ImalatTarihi"] = "2017-08-01 10:19:04";
$param["SeriNo"] = "123";
$param["TescilEdenTesisId"] = "31fd684c-f97d-48c1-a7fb-60f30f536d8d";
$param["UreticiId"] = "31fd684c-f97d-48c1-a7fb-60f30f536d8d";
// $param["UygunlukIsareti"] = "1";

$date   = date('d/m/Y');
$id     ="2ad9a9a9-adb9-4fb8-8fae-01e84aa72343";

try
{ 


  $sonuc = $client->TupTescil($id,$date,$param);
  print_r($sonuc);

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
   echo "Error ! ";
   echo $e -> getMessage ();
}
```

**Return Error**
Error ! The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'TupTescil'. End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 281.

**This example works with C#**

```
                Guid tupKimligi = new Guid("07FAF194-4E80-4359-95D9-011CA1F5A1D4"); 

            DateTime islemSaati = DateTime.Today;

            TupTescilBilgisi tescilBilgileri = new TupTescilBilgisi()  
            {
                BosAgirligi = 1,
                CalismaBasinci = 1,
                DoluAgirligi = 1,
                SonMuayeneTarihi = DateTime.Today,
                SonMuayeneYapanFirmaMersisNo = "123456789",
                SuKapasitesi = 1,
                TestBasinci = 1,
                DolumBasinci = 1,
                EtKalinligi = 1,
                ImalatTarihi = DateTime.Today,
                SeriNo = "123",
                TescilEdenTesisId = tesisId,
                UreticiId = ureticiId,
                UygunlukIsareti = TupUygunlukIsareti.Pi

            };


            Tup tescilSonuc = tsc.TupTescil(tupKimligi, DateTime.Today, tescilBilgileri);
```

**You can also look at the wsdl structure here**

[enter link description here](http://servis.sanayi.gov.tr:23001/TTSService/?wsdl)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Ugh. I remember dealing with this sort of thing 15 years ago when SOAP was used everywhere. Want to say it comes down to array depth/nesting. I think I often use a `stdClass()` instead of an array. Just for grins try: `$sonuc = $client->TupTescil($id, $date, array($param));`

Comment: I experimented with array same result :S

Comment: The "Error in deserializing body of request message for operation" is on server (WCF?) and returned to PHP client? Read the accepted answer and comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225735/error-in-deserializing-body-of-request-message-for-operation  But then not sure that would explain how the C# example works, would need to look at raw output of what was sent to see how it might differ. Tough one. Good luck!