# I want to generate the following wsdl soap api in php

Tags: php, xml, api, soap

I am trying to  generate the following request using php. I have tried generating the request in wizdler app on chrome.

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <CreatePolicy xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <Product>[string?]</Product>
            <XML>[string?]</XML>
        </CreatePolicy>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I have already tried many things but keep getting errors like `Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'CreatePolicy'. End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'param1' from namespace ''`

Any solutions?

Comment: Please share your php code and make it a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Share the wsdl file to see its definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in deserializing body of request message for operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225735/error-in-deserializing-body-of-request-message-for-operation)